# How can i make a php web service write to file?

Tags: php, web-services

When i call a php web service using soapUI, the soapUI return me  a error ,then i check the stack trace, i find

```
  #5 API.php(317): API::log(NULL, 'api_insert_rows...', NULL, Array, NULL, 'Inaccess object...')
```

then i login the machine of php web service and find the API.php

for debugging, i want write some variable to a text file,then i add this code to API.php

```
  $mf="1.txt";
  $fh=fopen($mf,'w');
  $stringData="aaa";
  fwrite($fh,$stringData);
  fclose($fh);
```

where 1.txt is created in same fold with API.php, and also change it's right by :

```
  chmod 777 1.txt
```

but when i using soapUI to send a soap message to php web sercice again , the 1.txt which should be written with "aaa" is still empty.
if i create a single php file which not a part of web service , only contain the IO code above, it can work,can anybody tell me what the reason?

Comment: Fix the error you are getting from SOAP and API will write to a file. Error is stopping your procedure from further executing.

Comment: Have you tried (if possible) to access API.php directly from URL to check if errors are displayed ? Maybe you encountered  an error before your debug code section ?

Comment: This seems like XY Problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: my IO code is before the line where error will happen,so i think it should not be stop.   and it is not possible to access API.php directly.

Comment: If SOAP is throwing error, nothing from API will be executed.